# git-retrieve single file from repository

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Retrieving a single file from Repository.

I am having repository with 10 directories/somefiles and pom.xml and one file with the name pom.xml(outside of directory).So i need to retrieve a pom.xml from that repo with history. Here one problem is pom.xml is in all 10 directories.When i try to retrieve with git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $(git ls-files | grep -v "pom.xml”)',this command retrieves all the pom.xml including the pom.xml in the directories.Can you help me to retrieve that only pom.xml excluding the pom.xml in directory.

Comment: Sounds like a strange use-case. Why can you not get the entire repository?

Comment: I can get the entire repository.But i only need one pom.xml which is outside the directory.Problem is i have other 10 directories in all those directories i have pom.xml and other files.

Comment: If you can get the entire repository and you need only one file, the usual (and usually correct) procedure is to get the entire repository, then use only the appropriate files from it. This is particularly relevant for poms, where dependencies can be very convoluted: just because you think you need only one pom right now doesn't mean that some day you'll need all ten of them.

Comment: Ok as you said i got the whole repository. As of now i want to get one pom which is not in the directories. I need a pom which is outside of the directories.So if any possibilities let me know.

Comment: git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch $(git ls-files | grep -v "pom.xml”)'  I tried in this way.Its fetching all the pom.xml in the directories too.

Comment: You mean it's in the root of the repository? Or do you mean you want a file that isn't in version control? Git can't help you get a file that it doesn't know about...

Comment: The file is in version control. I clone the repository into my local.

Comment: Hard to figure out what you mean.  You may need to update your question with a diagram. Assuming that pom.xml is in the root of your repo, that you have pulled your entire repo, and that you want that pom.xml, then you don't need to do anything else with git. The file is already there. Just use it in the normal way, like any other file.

Comment: I pulled the entire repo. The repo has got pom.xml and some directories. One pom.xml is not in a directory and some pom.xml are in the directories.I don't need the pom.xml in directories. I need a pom which is outside of directories . I cloned the entire repo to local. Repo looks like pom.xml Dir1 Dir2 Dir3.

Comment: In Dir again i have pom.xml and some other files.

Comment: You already said that you have the entire repo, in which case just... take the file. it's "there"... in the filesystem...

Comment: In this scenario i need to remove all those directories. I need only pom.xml which is outside of those Dir1,Dir2,Dir3. Any command. Need with history. its a task for me.sorry

Comment: This is not a git-related question any more, and a command depends on your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch just-pom
git filter-branch --index-filter '
                git read-tree --empty; git reset $GIT_COMMIT path/to/pom.xml
        ' -- just-pom --full-history -- path/to/pom.xml
```

That will preserve everything about that file's history.  Everything after the `--` on the last line is args to `git rev-list`, that's where you go to select exactly which commits feed the history you're constructing.

Comment: Great  jthill.  Thanks for the command.it worked perfect. awesome

Comment: I have small question on the above command you gave just-pom.Here why we need to give --just-pom in '-- just-pom --full-history -- path/to/pom.xml' its a branch name @jthill

Comment: That limits what filter-branch will rewrite.